# live ajax search doesn't auto populate until I submit once

Tags: php, ajax, search, live

This is actually a continuation of a question I posted here:

[live ajax search not working on chrome and ie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16869121/live-ajax-search-not-working-on-chrome-and-ie)

It turns out that if I submit a search query at least once, the 'live' part of my search function works in any browser.  For example, if I search for 'basketball' I get no suggested ajax search results, but if I submit it once, and start typing another search it then works and gives me suggested results. If I close and re-open the browser I have to do another search before it works again.  What would be the reason for this?

Comment: which version of IE and Chrome are you using ?

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated from version  jquery 1.7 itself and removed in later version.better use `.on()` .ref:http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Code becomes unstable when deprecated function are used. you have to use the alternative `.on()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [live ajax search not working on chrome and ie](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16869121/live-ajax-search-not-working-on-chrome-and-ie)

Comment: Don't create new "duplicate" questions. This should have been editted into the original one

Comment: I switched to using .on() but the same problem still persists.  This behavior is occurring in all browsers.  I have to do a search first and then the 'live' ajax results start working.

Comment: I posted a useful comment in the original question.